# I'm getting "Exception while reading from stream" when using postgresql-9.6 on CentOS

Tags: .net, npgsql

I don't get the error when using postgresql on OS X.
It happens when I do an UPDATE. I have no trouble doing SELECTs.

The complete stacktrace is:

> at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.Ensure (System.Int32 count, System.Boolean
>   dontBreakOnTimeouts) [0x0010b] in <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage (Npgsql.DataRowLoadingMode
>   dataRowLoadingMode, System.Boolean isPrependedMessage) [0x0000f] in
>   <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageWithPrepended
>   (Npgsql.DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode) [0x00017] in
>   <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage (Npgsql.DataRowLoadingMode
>   dataRowLoadingMode) [0x00000] in <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0 
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpecting[T] () [0x00000] in
>   <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResultInternal () [0x000d4] in
>   <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult () [0x00008] in
>   <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.Execute (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior)
>   [0x000fa] in <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal () [0x00024] in
>   <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00000] in
>   <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0    at Db+Denue.updateDenueRecord
>   (System.String id, System.String nombre, System.String razonSocial,
>   System.String claseActividad, System.String estrato, System.String
>   tipoVialidad, System.String calle, System.String numExterior,
>   System.String numInterior, System.String colonia, System.String cp,
>   System.String ubicacion, System.String telefono, System.String
>   correoE, System.String sitioInternet, System.String tipo,
>   System.Double latitud, System.Double longitud) [0x00197] in
>   /Users/laygr/Desktop/InegiReplica/InegiReplica/Db.fs:323    at
>   DbApiBridge.DenueResponse.IncludeInDb (InegiApi+InegiApi+DenueResponse
>   ) [0x00199] in
>   /Users/laygr/Desktop/InegiReplica/InegiReplica/DbApiBridge.fs:27    at
>   MyWebApi.Program+processRequest@47-8.Invoke
>   (InegiApi+InegiApi+DenueResponse dr) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/laygr/Desktop/InegiReplica/InegiReplica/InegiReplica.fs:48
>   at MyWebApi.Program+processRequest@38-7.Invoke
>   (System.Tuple`4[T1,T2,T3,T4] tupledArg) [0x00180] in
>   /Users/laygr/Desktop/InegiReplica/InegiReplica/InegiReplica.fs:47

Comment: This could indicate an Npgsql bug which causes it to lose protocol sync with PostgreSQL. Is the error easily reproducible? If so, please open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql with a code sample (as short and easy to run as possible).

Comment: Later, I noticed that I was using npgsql 3.1, not the latest. The problem dissapeared when I upgraded both npgsql and .Net, so, unfortunately, I don't know what solved it.